# Affine Transformation matrix for mapping a triangle to another

Tags: matlab, affine-geometry

I'm trying to write a function in Matlab that will give me a matrix `T` that can be used to multiply points in homogeneous coordinates. This is achieved my mapping a `triangle1` to a `triangle2` (I'm given 2x3 matrices witch each, and each column is a vertex in 2D).

The way I approached it was by getting each triangle to the origin and placing them in extended matrices (`A` and `B`). Then `T` should be `A^-1 * B`. I get row reduced of `[A | B]` which will give me `[I | A^-1 * B]`, then extract the `A^-1 * B` portion to return as `T`

This is the code I came up with:

```
function T = affineMapping(triangle1,triangle2)

v1_x = triangle1(1,1); v1_y = triangle1(2,1); v2_x = triangle1(1,2); v2_y = triangle1(2,2); v3_x = triangle1(1,3); v3_y = triangle1(2,3);

w1_x = triangle2(1,1); w1_y = triangle2(2,1); w2_x = triangle2(1,2); w2_y = triangle2(2,2); w3_x = triangle2(1,3); w3_y = triangle2(2,3);

%Here I go from a basis triangle (1,0), (0,1), (0,0) to triangle 1
A = [ (v1_x - v3_x) (v1_y - v3_y) 0,
      (v2_x - v3_x) (v2_y - v3_y) 0,
      v3_x v3_y 1];

%Here I go from a basis triangle (1,0), (0,1), (0,0) to triangle 2
B = [ (w1_x - w3_x) (w1_y - w3_y) 0,
      (w2_x - w3_x) (w2_y - w3_y) 0,
      w3_x w3_y 1];

T = [A,B];
T = rref(T);
T = [T(:,4), T(:,5), T(:,6)];
```

When I test it however, it doesn't seem to be correct. I can't pinpoint where I went wrong. Is the math for obtaining `T` correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that your linear transformation is $T(p)=Ap$, where $p$ is in homogeneous coordinates. Let $p_i=[t_{1ix},t_{1iy},1]^T$ and $q_i=[t_{2ix},t_{2iy},1]^T$ where $t_{kix}$ and $t_{kiy}$ are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of vertex $i$ in triangle $k$.

It should be clear that
$$
q_1=Ap_1,\ 
q_2=Ap_2,\ 
q_3=Ap_3,
$$
which can be rewritten in block matrix notation as
$$
[q_1,q_2,q_3]=A[p_1,p_2,p_3].
$$
This gives the transformation matrix as
$$
A=[q_1,q_2,q_3][p_1,p_2,p_3]^{-1}.
$$

Spoiler solution:

> The relevant Matlab code, given your inputs, is A=[triangle2;1,1,1]/[triangle1;1,1,1].